# How to start a new GUI form in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA uses a different approach to GUI forms, instead of extending JFrame, it hides all GUI code in .form files and instantiates the form in main() of Bound class.

Now for example, I have two forms in the project. Login and Page.

In any other IDE, I would have called Page.java after successful login using

```
Page page = new Page();
page.setVisible(true);
```

it works because Page extends JFrame class and thus has setVisible() method. But how do I do that in Intellij?

Edit:
Page.java

```
public class Page {
    private JButton uploadAFileButton;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton downloadSelectedFileButton;
    private JButton deleteSelectedFileButton;
    private JList list1;
    private JButton refreshFileListButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("ControlForm");
        frame.setContentPane(new Page().panel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: The '.form' file is just a representation of the UI based on the core Swing components.  What does your form extend from?

Comment: If a gui form is created using the built-in Form designer, the form doesn't extend from anything. I included the source of Page.java

Comment: It looks like it has the ability to put most components into a JPanel, here named panel1, but something I'm sure that it will allow you to rename. So why not give your class a `getPanel1()` method or something similar and more appropriately named for your program, and then use your components in this way?

Comment: Whats stopping you from adding `extends JFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

if page class is GUI form,the you should extend it using JFrame. If not you can't call `page.setVisible(true);`.So your page class should be like this.

```java
public class Page extends JFrame {
    private JButton uploadAFileButton;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton downloadSelectedFileButton;
    private JButton deleteSelectedFileButton;
    private JList list1;
    private JButton refreshFileListButton;
}
```